# ASP.net MVC window.open URL not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, href

My existing code is here:

```
function opendocpdf_click() {
        var docloc = '/App_Data/Test_Project_Documents.pdf'
        window.open(docloc);
    }
```

The above code doesn't working, it seems 404.8 not found error. but the below code is working fine, what can i do for above code can work.

```
 function opendocpdf_click() {                       
     var docloc = 'E:/palanisamy/Projects/Sample/App_Data/Test_Project_Documents.pdf'
        window.open(docloc);
    }
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET will not serve files stored in `App_Data`; it is a [special folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx). If you want the files publicly available, you'll need to do one of the following:

1. Store the files in a different, regular folder.
2. Create a handler or page in ASP.NET that will take the name of a file and look for it in App_Data, and then response binary write it back to the client.

Comment: hi, can i change like that  var docloc = '/content/MHAR_Project_Documents.pdf'

Comment: @Palanisamy.gis Sure, if you physically move the files into `content`, that would be easiest.

Comment: yeah, thank you... but it seems the error again"HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."